# Java equivalent of this JavaScript regex code?

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have this JavaScript code:

```
highlightTerm = "h=e;?l*l{o";
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replace(/[\\;]/g, ' ');
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replace(/([{}<>\/=:])(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/g, '\\$&');
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replace(/"/g, '\"');
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.trim();

console.log(highlightTerm); // "h\=e ?l*l\{o"
```

I am trying to find the Java equivalent. I've tried the following bit it gives a different result:

```
String highlightTerm = "h=e;?l*l{o";
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replaceAll("[\\;]", " ");
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replaceAll("([{}<>\\/=:])(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)", "\\$&");
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replaceAll("[\"]", "\\\"");
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.trim();

System.out.println(highlightTerm); // "h=e ?l*l{o"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to double escape backslashes in Java, since you're passing the regex as a string - there is no string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `'\\$&'` is Javascript mean whole matched string but doesn't mean the same in Java. I don't think there is a one-line solution in Java to solve this problem, but this code should work:

```
String highlightTerm = "h=e;?l*l{o";
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replaceAll("[\\;]", " ");
//highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replace(/([{}<>\/=:])(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/g, '\\$&');

//These lines are replacement for the above line
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([{}<>\\/=:])(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(highlightTerm);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    String replacement = "\\" + matcher.group(1);
    builder.append(highlightTerm, i, matcher.start());
    builder.append(replacement);
    i = matcher.end();
}
builder.append(highlightTerm.substring(i));
highlightTerm = builder.toString();

//rest of your code
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.replaceAll("[\"]", "\\\"");
highlightTerm = highlightTerm.trim();

System.out.println(highlightTerm);
```